# How to use not selector in jquery with multiple classes as one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have in my HTML div with one class tag and one with 2 classes that look like one class.

```
<body>
    <div class="ad-container left">
    <div class="ad-container">
    <div class="mobile-ad larger">
    <div class="mobile-ad">
</body>
```

Whats the proper way to use the not selector in jQuery to support all 4 div's and not ignore anything else in body.

I currently have

```
$('body:not(.ad-container,.ad-container.left,.mobile-ad.larger,.mobile-ad)')
```

It seems to work without any problems.

But something tells me I need to split the left and larger classes into seperate elements by comma.

Something like this

```
$('body:not(.ad-container,.left,.mobile-ad,.larger)')
```

Here is the full code:

```
     $(function () {
        $('body:not(.ad-container,.ad-container.left,.mobile-ad.larger,.mobile-ad)').on('selectstart', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

It's used to disable the left double click selection but still be able to click on ads.
Which one should I use?

Comment: what do you really want to do

Comment: Try `$('body div').not('.ad-container,.ad-container.left,.mobile-ad.larger,.mobile-ad)')` But u select `body` which will contain all of these :)

Comment: `$('body :not(.ad-container, .mobile-ad)')`

Comment: @TusharGupta I looks for a body element without the said classed... OP has the class for the descendant elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny will it still target all 4?

Comment: .ad-container and .mobile-ad already select all four containers, so you do not need the other ones.

Comment: yes... because those classes are repeated

Comment: @SSpoke do you want to select those 4 or select all elements other than those 4

Comment: makes sense I had this bug with the mouse keeps blinking from disabling double left click selection with jQuery and I still want the ads to be clickable, I updated the code with the full code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh yeah now updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using

```
$('body :not(.ad-container, .mobile-ad)')
```